# Does the QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter have speed issues on Windows? Or only Linux?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, wifi-driver, wireless-card

[This post on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1357555/824054) links to several users who have problems with the QCA9377. Personally, I cannot get it over 7 MB/s no matter what I try.

**Is this problem unique to Linux, suggesting it is a driver issue, or is it a limitation of the card itself?** For example, is there evidence of Windows users facing the same problem?

Comment: This problem occurs in both Windows and Linux. Try to turn off Bluetooth in the computer.

Comment: @harrymc I'm pretty sure that I've already got that disabled. Part of the output of `service bluetooth status` is `Active: inactive (dead)`.

Comment: You may need to try the latest driver as well as older drivers, in the hope that one will work.

Comment: That and/or firmware, as mentioned in your own link. Regarding your actual question I'm not aware of complaints by Windows users but that is as good as trying to prove a negative. It would make a lot more sense asking for help to troubleshoot in Linux, here or in more apt Q&As.

Comment: @harrymc I'll experiment. I've already done some experimentation and seen no change in behaviour.

Comment: BTW, you could test in Windows without installing it, e.g., Hirens Boot CD PE (Hiren’s BootCD PE ), which uses WinPE and has network access and a browsers.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik My attempts to live boot Windows have traditionally failed extremely badly. I last tried a few days ago.

Comment: WinPE (and similar Win RE) are *intended* for booting from alternate media. The Macrium Rescue Environment uses it, as well as Hiren's Boot CD, and I've not had trouble with either. Is your PC so new that it indiscriminately enforces TPM restrictions on boot?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Quite the opposite. I've been testing on old machines.

Comment: When you say 7MB/s are you talking about 7 * 2^20 8-bit Bytes per second? So around 59Mbps (millions of bits per second)? If so, that sounds right for a non-MIMO device like a QCA9377 on a 20MHz-wide channel like is commonly used on 2.4GHz. For the QCA9377 to reach its top throughput (after overhead) of around 300Mbps (36MiB/s), you need to connect to an AP that is doing 802.11ac (in 5GHz of course) on a clean 80MHz-wide channel. And you need to be in the same room as the router, with clear line-of-sight.

Comment: @Spiff Perhaps there is a unit that I am not being consistent with. What I know is that an Xbox One reports that I get 40 of its unit and that a tool on Ubuntu just told me that I'm getting "6.04**MiB/s**" (exact quote, so that one can't be wrong). I believe that the Xbox One reports **Mb/s**.

Comment: 6.04 MiB = 6.33339904 MB so everything @Spiff already commented stands.

Comment: @ChanganAuto So in plain idiot-proof terms, the Xbox One and the Linux machine are reporting very similar speeds? Sorry, it's very late.

Comment: @J.Mini Thanks for clarifying. It still sounds reasonable for how that client chipset would perform on a 20MHz-wide channel. To get better performance, you need a clean (low noise, low contention) 80MHz-wide channel and good signal strength.

Comment: I don't know XBox. If it's reporting in Mbps then 40 Mbps = 5 MB/s, roughly the same.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Online screenshots suggest it reports Mb/s.

Comment: This suggests otherwise: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/xbox/forum/all/why-mbs-instead-of-mbs-on-xbox-dl/0f564ccb-73e8-4537-b659-4123ba77c7a4 In any case the crux of the matter still is do you actually have a problem or because you don't understand this kind of unit conversions - Google is your friend -  you created for yourself a problem of (wrong) perception? The above about this being a somewhat dumb question notwithstanding.

Comment: @J.Mini, Age has little to do with it. I regularly use Macrium Rescue Environment , *32 bit*, to image a 2009 Acer D250. Perhaps it's BIOS or other settings getting in the way on your machine? (One assumes you know to use a 32-bit ISO for a 32-bit machine.)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Don't worry too much. It seems the author is just confused about units.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, Sorry, I was a bit confused myself; sometimes I byte off more than I can chew.

Comment: @Spiff I have confirmed that the Xbox reports its units in *Mbps*. I will take time to think about the consequences of this.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149639/discussion-on-question-by-j-mini-does-the-qca9377-802-11ac-wireless-network-ada); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.